# How to get the total instance of the :contains() Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, contains

I have these divs

```
<div id="content" style="display:none">**Content1 goes here**</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Content2 goes here</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Content3 goes here</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Content4 goes here</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">**Content1 goes here too**</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">**Content1 goes here again**</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Content4 goes here part 2</div>
```

I have my jquery contains selector

```
$( "div:contains('Content1')" ).css( "display", "block" );
```

If there's a match (i.e. Content1), then all matched DIVs will be displayed.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to know how many matches occurred? For "Content1", it should say 3 records. Also, if there's no match, it will say "0 results".

Comment: `$("<selector>").length` ... in your case use this `$( "div:contains('Content1')" ).length`

Comment: the jQuery object has a length property which can be used in this case

Comment: Also, IDs should be **unique**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example. I hope this helps :)

```
  var matches = $("div:contains('Content1')").length;

   alert(matches);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silkherb/rvecpu5d/2/