# How to get the total instance of the :contains() Selector using an Array with multiple matches in a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is a follow-up query for [How to get the total instance of the :contains() Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25438855/how-to-get-the-total-instance-of-the-contains-selector)

I have this array loop issue on getting the total match using contains:selector...

Here are my variables -

```
var filterarray = ["Content1", "goes"];

<div id="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here too</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here again</div>
<div id="content" style="display:none">extra node</div>
```

Here's my script -

```
totalSum = 0;
for (i=0;i<filterarray.length;i++){ 
        $( "div[id^=content]:contains('"+ filterarray[i] +"')").css( "display", "block" );      
        totalSum += $( "div[id^=content]:contains('"+ filterarray[i] +"')").length;      
    }

$("#results").append("Total Results: " +totalSum);
```

The results shows = 6, wherein it should only be 3 because the div is already in "block". I think the count goes for each "Content1" = 3 and "goes" = 3, total of 6.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to show only 3 and ignore if there are multiple matches (or duplicates) within a DIV instance?

Comment: This might help you: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.unique/

http://jsfiddle.net/xb14h1ev/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here too</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here again</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">extra node</div>

<div id="results"></div>
```

JS:

```
var filterarray = ["Content1", "goes"];
$(function(){
    totalSum = 0;
    var divs = [];
    for (i=0;i<filterarray.length;i++){ 
        $( "div.content:contains('"+ filterarray[i] +"')").css( "display", "block" );
        $.merge(divs, $( "div.content:contains('"+ filterarray[i] +"')"));
    }
    totalSum = $.unique(divs).length;
    $("#results").append("Total Results: " +totalSum);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First advice use classes instead of ids! Because id means **UNICAL IDENTIFICATOR**. Read about this [note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544010/css-div-id-vs-div-class).

So assume you have next html nodes

```
<div class="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here too</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">Content1 goes here again</div>
<div class="content" style="display:none">extra node</div>
```

Iterate all nodes with **content** class.

```
var nodes = $(".content");
var filterarray = ["Content1", "goes"];
var total = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    var current = $(nodes[i]);
    var text = current.text();
    var res = filterarray.reduce(function(p, a){
        return p && (text.indexOf(a) != -1);
    }, true);
    if(res) total++;
}

console.log(total)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W4Km8/1767/)